# Trying to transpose the matrix from a 3x4 to a 4x3 in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments

I have to read a file from the command line, and also set the matrix rows and cols. When I run my program(below):

```
python3 transpose.py               matrix                                                 3 4
        (current code below) (file with numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13)  (matrix row,cols)
```

printed all together should return:

```
The empty matrix is:[[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
The original matrix is:
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12

The transposed matrix is:
1 5 9
2 6 10
3 7 11
4 8 12
```

Here is my transpose.py Ive spent around 10 hours on it and can't get it to work, I just can't figure out what else to do!

```
 import sys
from scanner import *


def main():
    readinput(sys.argv[1],[2])
    size = 3
    rows = size
    cols = rows
    makeList(size)
    matrix(rows,cols)
    manipulateMatrix(matrix(rows,cols))
    print(manipulateMatrix(matrix(rows,cols)))
    print("The original matrix is: ")
    displayMatrix(manipulateMatrix(matrix(rows,cols)))
    transposeSquare(manipulateMatrix(matrix(rows,cols)),size)
    print (transposeSquare(manipulateMatrix(matrix(rows,cols)),size))
    print("The transposed matrix: ")
    displayMatrix(transposeSquare(manipulateMatrix(matrix(rows,cols)),size))    
def readinput(filename,matrix):
    s = Scanner(filename)
    r = s.readtoken()
    while r != "":
        r = int(r)
        c = s.readint()
        v = s.readint()
        matrix[r][c]=v
        r = s.readtoken()
    s.close()

def makeList(size):
    lyst = []
    for i in range(size):
        lyst = lyst + [None]
    return lyst

def matrix(rows,cols):
    matrix = makeList(rows)
    for i in range(rows):
        matrix[i] = makeList(cols)
        return matrix

def manipulateMatrix(m):
    rows = len(m)
    cols = len(m[0])
    count = 1
    for r in range(0,rows,1):
        for c in range(0,cols,1):
            m[r][c] = count
            count += 1
    return m

def transposeSquare(m,size):
    for r in range(0,size):
         for c in range(0,size):
            m[r][c],m[c][r] = m[c][r],m[r][c]
    return m

def displayMatrix(m):
    m == rows == cols
    for r in range(0,size):
        for c in range(0,cols,1):
            print(m[r][c],end = "")
        print()
    return          
main()
```

right now I am currently stuck at

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "transpose.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "transpose.py", line 6, in main
    readinput(sys.argv[1],[2])
  File "transpose.py", line 27, in readinput
    matrix[r][c]=v
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Note that the title of your question actually has nothing to do with your *actual* problem (which is in a very specific part of your code, far from the "transpose" functionality).

Comment: Read error message. Fix the problem. Move on to next issue later..

Comment: Also, unless this is homework (which does seem pretty likely), there is functionality for all of these matrix operations in the numpy package.

Comment: its a practice for our final, and we aren't allowed to use numpy

Comment: @user2864740 I don't know how to fix it, I wish I had the ability to just "Fix the problem", but that's why I came on here for help. I was posting that as the question because that is my ultimate goal, to transpose.

Comment: You cannot get that error message from the code you posted.

Comment: @AndrewJaffe So how do I solve the readinput argument issue? I know what the issue means, I just don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @larsmans
'        $ python3 transpose.py matrix 3 4
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "transpose.py", line 66, in <module>
        main()
      File "transpose.py", line 6, in main
        readinput(sys.argv[1])
    TypeError: readinput() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

is what I keep getting :/

Comment: @user3754670 Then what you're running is not the code you posted.

Comment: @larsmans What should it be returning? I don't really know any other way of showing you the code that im running :/ I literally copy pasted from my vim into here.

Comment: It should crash in `matrix[r][c]=v` because the second argument to `readinput` is wrong. But there are two arguments to that function, and it takes two, so double-check your code and the stuff you posted.

Comment: @larsmans actually you're right, the one im running now doesn't have the sys.arvg[2], pardon my sleep depravity haha. will update the error

Answer (score 3):

Transposing a 2D list is much simpler. Use the [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) together with the `*` unpacking operator:

```
>>> matrix = [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]
>>> new = list(zip(*matrix))  # call to list not necessary in Python 2
>>> new
[(1, 5, 9), (2, 6, 10), (3, 7, 11), (4, 8, 12)]
```

or, if you don't want tuples:

```
>>> new = [list(tup) for tup in zip(*matrix)]
>>> new
[[1, 5, 9], [2, 6, 10], [3, 7, 11], [4, 8, 12]]
```

Comment: Hey, I just wanted to write this. :-)

Comment: we have to read in the matrix from a file into the program, our grader will input random numbers from separate files to check the program :(

Comment: @user3754670: That approach will still work. Or do you not know how to read a file? Your question is a bit confusing...

Answer (score 0):

Use the numpy library. it is designed for this purpose, runs the numerical in C/C++ code and much faster than doing it in python and having to debug it.

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array(<your list matrix here>)
print m.shape # to see the shape of your matrix
mt = m.T #m.T transpose the matrix
print m.shape
print m
```

Comment: im taking a python class, we are graded/checked by basic python guidelines. aka no numpy :(